# iTunes App Store API for Querying My Apps, Editing My Apps, and Uploading New Apps

Tags: app-store

Does Apple offer a web service API for querying iOS apps I sell under my account, editing these apps, and uploading new ones? If so, could someone provide a link?

The only thing I could find is the Application Loader tool that allows bulk creation operation for IAP via a file.  Does this tool support bulk creation of apps?  Does this tool support editing existing IAP?

https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/UsingApplicationLoader.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Update

The [App Store Connect API](https://developer.apple.com/app-store-connect/api/) offers API access to a limited set of App Store connect features.

---

### Old Answer

There is no web service API for performing private actions available only to you.  You must login to iTunes Connect and do it there.

There is a web service for accessing publicly available information.  [It is documented here](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html).

For example, for more info on the Yelp app, you could send this request:

> https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=284910350

Which will return JSON like this:

```
{
  "resultCount": 1,
  "results": [
    {
      "kind": "software",
      "features": [
        "iosUniversal"
      ],
      "supportedDevices": [
        "all"
      ],
      "isGameCenterEnabled": false,
      "screenshotUrls": [
        "http://a1283.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/084/Purple/v4/d7/10/4e/d7104e7c-69b9-c30e-fb74-dc9ad4907e5d/mzl.qhnhnswp.png",
        "http://a1583.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/091/Purple/v4/f2/9e/1f/f29e1ff0-15ae-955b-9470-95e777e0d302/mzl.ehinvjli.png",
        "http://a232.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/080/Purple/v4/fa/be/87/fabe8765-de35-ae10-6eba-4b77dee9579c/mzl.ypncttex.png",
        "http://a1190.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/114/Purple2/v4/86/68/86/86688674-4540-b317-9e1f-fc2c8adede50/mzl.ekbdqwzg.png",
        "http://a296.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/115/Purple2/v4/b6/ca/e1/b6cae1d2-5754-d092-c2c3-09dce16a5b86/mzl.xroiibzd.png"
      ],
      "ipadScreenshotUrls": [
        "http://a1855.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/069/Purple2/v4/27/53/59/27535982-a8ab-752b-1352-14376dbd52fa/mzl.pzkmvqsc.1024x1024-65.jpg",
        "http://a1384.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/120/Purple/v4/d8/61/72/d86172b0-c012-b520-aaea-0fe405af8220/mzl.ayvdvsyz.1024x1024-65.jpg",
        "http://a1714.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/107/Purple/v4/d4/e6/54/d4e65417-151e-c358-cf46-67034eb1c809/mzl.cqcnsrnw.1024x1024-65.jpg",
        "http://a668.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/115/Purple2/v4/9f/0f/0c/9f0f0c76-86cf-5af0-7d62-e57d05cdb7d9/mzl.gdkkhahb.1024x1024-65.jpg",
        "http://a886.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/080/Purple2/v4/4e/2c/e8/4e2ce8be-f69d-2fd9-b79a-e9a689dd1ad6/mzl.vjffwbxj.1024x1024-65.jpg"
      ],
      "artworkUrl60": "http://a1154.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/093/Purple2/v4/df/d2/d1/dfd2d173-7901-1c41-fcc3-ea953e698961/57.png",
      "artworkUrl512": "http://a1157.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/108/Purple/v4/db/b7/fb/dbb7fb10-29a7-4771-e781-38fffee81c85/mzl.atjqxuth.png",
      "artistViewUrl": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/yelp/id284910353?uo=4",
      "artistId": 284910353,
      "artistName": "Yelp",
      "price": 0,
      "version": "6.5.1",
      "description": "Looking for a burrito joint open now?  An Irish pub nearby?  A gas station you can drive to before your tank hits empty?  Yelp for your iPhone or iPad is here to help.  Use us to search for places to eat, shop, drink, relax and play then read reviews from an active community of locals in the know.   \n\nFEATURES:\n★ Search for businesses near you \n★ Tap quick links to find nearby bars, restaurants, cafes and more\n★ Narrow your searches by 'hood, distance, price, and what's open now\n★ Browse reviews to read what's great (and not so great) in your city\n★ Find great Deals offered by your favorite local businesses on iPhone\n★ Add tips, photos, and draft reviews for your favorite businesses\n★ Check-in and share on Facebook and Twitter\n★ Make reservations on OpenTable without leaving the Yelp app\n★ Look up addresses and phone numbers for thousands of businesses, then call or map them from your iPhone or iPad\n★ Yelp does augmented reality with Monocle. Overlay business information onto the world around you.",
      "currency": "USD",
      "genres": [
        "Travel",
        "Navigation"
      ],
      "genreIds": [
        "6003",
        "6010"
      ],
      "releaseDate": "2008-07-11T07:00:00Z",
      "sellerName": "Yelp, Inc.",
      "bundleId": "com.yelp.yelpiphone",
      "trackId": 284910350,
      "trackName": "Yelp",
      "primaryGenreName": "Travel",
      "primaryGenreId": 6003,
      "releaseNotes": "New in 6.5.1:\nJust to show how much we love our Yelpers, we're knocking out two big feature requests with this release:\n☆ Apparently 300 characters per Tip wasn't enough for you to fully express yourself. We dig that. This release gives you 200 more.\n☆ From the \"More Reviews\" list on iPhone, pull down to expose a review search box. Now you can skip the other stuff and find out exactly what people think about the \"carne asada burrito\" at that new Mexican spot down the street.\n\nNew in 6.5:\n☆ We gave our iPad business page a whole lot of love. It's now more streamline and clear, with more emphasis on business photos. In addition, we're now showing Yelp Deals and our new \"Explore the Menu\" feature.\n☆ Yelp search just got more social: Now you can see which friends are checked in to businesses directly from your search results.\n☆ Getting to a restaurant just after closing is a major bummer. Now we'll indicate if a business will be closing soon or is just about to open.\n☆ We also got in a TON of bug fixes and enhancements: showing your review first in the reviews list, supporting updated reviews on iPad, swipe-able photos on the business page, and huge speed improvements on iPhone5!",
      "formattedPrice": "Free",
      "wrapperType": "software",
      "trackCensoredName": "Yelp",
      "languageCodesISO2A": [
        "SV",
        "TR",
        "NB",
        "DA",
        "DE",
        "EN",
        "ES",
        "FI",
        "FR",
        "IT",
        "NL",
        "PL"
      ],
      "fileSizeBytes": "18176675",
      "contentAdvisoryRating": "12+",
      "averageUserRatingForCurrentVersion": 3.5,
      "userRatingCountForCurrentVersion": 74,
      "artworkUrl100": "http://a1157.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/108/Purple/v4/db/b7/fb/dbb7fb10-29a7-4771-e781-38fffee81c85/mzl.atjqxuth.png",
      "trackViewUrl": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/yelp/id284910350?mt=8&uo=4",
      "trackContentRating": "12+",
      "averageUserRating": 3.5,
      "userRatingCount": 170887
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is great info.  Is there a way to upload bulk apps via the App Loader using a file or is this just for new IAPs.

Comment: You can only upload one at a time.  You can also only create one app at a time in iTunes Connect.

Comment: @AaronBrager..is there any way we could know about the number of install of the particular application?